# Android - Retrofit with inherited interface is not working properly in release mode

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Currently I am facing this weird issue.

I have created the retrofit instance and I have two api interfaces. ApiClientOld interface implemented ApiClient interface and overridden the base method.

I am creating the instance with retrofit for both the interfaces. But both instance are referring the base method.

Please check the example code below.

**Below example is working fine in debug mode and not working in release mode.**

I am curious to know that why the code working like this.
Please anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!!

```
interface ApiClient {
    @GET("owner/details")
    suspend fun getDetails(): Response<Details>
}

interface ApiClientOld : ApiClient {
    @GET("user/details")
    override suspend fun getDetails(): Response<Details>
}


fun createApiClient(retrofit: Retrofit, useOld: Boolean): ApiClient {
    return if (useOld)
        retrofit.create(ApiClientOld::class.java)
    else
        retrofit.create(ApiClient::class.java)
}

suspend fun makeAPI(retrofit: Retrofit) {
    val apiClient = createApiClient(retrofit, useOld=true)
    val response = apiClient.getDetails()
    // This should call the overridden method in ApiClientOld (user/details path)
    // But It is calling the base ApiClient (owner/details path)
}
```

makeAPI function should call the api (user/details) from the derived interface. But It is calling the base interface method (owner/details).  -- **only in Release mode**

release configuration:

```
{
debuggable false
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please make `minifyEnabled false` in the release configuration. try again

Answer (score 0):

So as this issue relates to [obfuscation](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code) then another option is to [customize which code to keep from obfuscation](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#keep-code) by using @Keep annotation.

```
@Keep
interface ApiClientOld : ApiClient {
   @GET("user/details")
   override suspend fun getDetails(): Response<Details>
}
```